# Always show application menu bar in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-13.04

Is there a way to force the application menu to always be visible (as opposed to only showing when the cursor is hovered over the top panel)? I'm talking about the application-specific "File", "Edit", etc., menu.

In previous version of Ubuntu, there was a PPA that could be used to install something called "Unity Revamped", which was a patched version of Unity that had some tweaks (dodge windows and the ability to always show the menu bar). However, Unity Revamped does not seem to be compatible with Raring.

Is there anything like that or another workaround for Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Also visit: http://askubuntu.com/q/22486